# In I.Q. and Cognitive Tests, What Sequence Patterns Should be Applied?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, measurement, intelligence, cognition

Nearly every I.Q. and Cognitive test seems to ask questions for the "next item in the sequence".   But, there just seems to be so many possibilities, and I can usually find a way that all of the multiple-guess choices could be true.

But, what are the test-givers actually looking for?

**For example:**

1. Rotate the image clockwise or counter clockwise on the page, (around the Z axis).
2. Flip the image around the Y Axis, (Vertical Mirror).
3. Flip the image around the X Axis, (Horizontal Mirror).
4. ... Combinations of the above?
5. Cycle the colors through sequences, (like red, green, blue ...),
6. etc., etc.,

Sometimes, I feel that because I am left-handed (or just odd?) - the "simple" and "obvious" choices seem very, very, relative.

**Question:**

1. What are the actual patterns they are expecting people to apply?   If multiple patterns apply, which one do you choose?
2. And, these tests often direct the test-taker to choose the "simplest" or "most obvious" solution; but, how do you know which one is which?

Comment: I was going to add a snappy remark saying, "Why not ask someone with a higher IQ?", but then I realized that this is actually a great question. If the nature of a correct answer on a sequence pattern IQ test question cannot be described, then what is it really measuring? If it is actually measuring conformity to unwritten social rules, it can be argued that such questions are not a valid test of IQ.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - Thank you for saying that.  Yes, that is my implication - but I have no idea how to write that as a question.  Feel free to edit.  (Perhaps I need a higher I.Q.?)